# python web scraping with missing source code

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the pricing information from these two websites: [site1](http://www.strem.com/catalog/v/29-6720/17/copper_1300746-79-5) and [site2](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/777692?lang=en&region=US)
I am using Python and packages BeautifulSoup and requests.

What I realized is that the pricing section is not available in the source code for both sites. So I am wondering how I can scrape the data.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If you highlight the section and view element, you see the information. But if you just check out the source code, then you do not see the pricing section

Comment: Why does the post marked with such a strange "Too broad" flag? The question is very specific about a specific problem on a specific web-site.

Comment: would you be able to comment on the second link? can I approach it in a similar fashion?

Comment: furthermore, do you know if I could get the same information searching by CAS #? Ideally, I would like to submit a list of cas #'s to python and be able to return the prices.

Comment: I apologize if I am asking too much. But I am new to Python and have spent the last month working on this code to no avail. Thank you again for your kind help.

Comment: Please split the issues into separate specific questions. The second case appears to be different from the first one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that first you need to select a country to see the prices.

In technical sense, you need to make a POST request to `http://www.strem.com/catalog/index.php` to select a country, then you can get the prices:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "http://www.strem.com/catalog/v/29-6720/17/copper_1300746-79-5"
session = requests.session()
p = session.post("http://www.strem.com/catalog/index.php", {'country': 'USA',
                                                            'page_function': 'select_country',
                                                            'item_id': '7211',
                                                            'group_id': '17'})

response = session.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
print [td.text.strip() for td in soup.find_all('td', class_='price')]
```

This prints:

```
[u'US$85.00', u'US$285.00', u'US$1,282.00', u'US$3,333.00']
```

A more elegant solution would be to submit a form using [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) package:

```
import cookielib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize

URL = "http://www.strem.com/catalog/v/29-6720/17/copper_1300746-79-5"
browser = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
browser.set_cookiejar(cj)
browser.open(URL)
browser.select_form(nr=1)
browser.form['country'] = ['USA']
browser.submit()

data = browser.response().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print [td.text.strip() for td in soup.find_all('td', class_='price')]
```

Prints:

```
[u'US$85.00', u'US$285.00', u'US$1,282.00', u'US$3,333.00']
```

Comment: wow, it has been some time since I have seen such an elaborate and awesome answer. :+1: